# Rails - 12-hour time input - Display time input using 3 boxes: HH(blank padded) - MM - AM/PM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, simple-form

Is there a way for rails to output a time select in this format:

[image]

Blank padded hour, minute, and AM/PM?

time_select seems to do it in two boxes: HHAM/PM : MM. This personally bewilders me as to why whoever contributed that to rails would code it like that. I've never seen that design practice anywhere (at least in the US. Is this normal in other countries?)

I am using simpleform, but can't seem to find a way using that either. So a solution with or out simpleform would work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this with the following code (if the form object is 'derp'):

```
<div class="timepicker">
  <select class="hour form-control" name="derp[hour]">
    <%= options_for_select((1..12).to_a, @derp.time ? @derp.time.strftime('%l').to_i : nil) %>
  </select>
  <span class="colon">:</span>
  <select class="minute form-control" name="derp[minute]" >
    <%= options_for_select(['00', '15', '30', '45'], @derp.time ? @derp.time.strftime('%M').to_i : nil) %>
  </select>
  <select class="meridiem form-control" name="derp[meridiem]" >
    <%= options_for_select(['AM', 'PM'], @derp.time ? @derp.time.strftime('%p') : nil) %>
  </select>
</div>
```

Then in the derp model:

```
attr_accessor :hour, :minute, :meridiem

after_validation :parse_time

def parse_time
  if hour and minute and meridiem
    self.time = DateTime.parse("#{hour}:#{minute}#{meridiem}") 
  end
end
```